# JQuery loop through table get ID and change values in a specific column

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, html-table

I have a page with 2-3 tables. In those tables I want to change the text of a specific column located in `<thead>` and also a value in each `<td>` line, and I would like to get the `id` from each line.

What is the fastest way to do this, performance-wise?

### HTML

**Table-Layout:**

```
<table class="ms-viewtable">
   <thead id="xxx">
      <tr class ="ms-viewheadertr">
         <th>
         <th>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="ms-itmHover..." id="2,1,0">
         <td>
         <td>
      <tr class="ms-itmHover..." id="2,2,0">
         <td>
         <td>
</table>
```

### JavaScript

**Script with that I started:**

```
$('.ms-listviewtable').each(function () {
   var table = $(this);

   $table.find('tr > th').each(function () {
      //Code here
   });

   $table.find('tr > td').each(function () {
      //Code here
   });
```

How can I get the Id? Is this there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: In pretty certain that a comma is not a valid character to be used inside an `id`.

Comment: Valid characters in *ID* attribute:http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/1451422

Comment: [those IDentifiers are valid in HTML5, no problem](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id).

Comment: your IDs are on the _rows_, but you're iterating over the _columns_

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id of an element by calling `.attr` on `"id"` i.e. `$(this).attr("id");`.

Comment: Nooooo!  `$(this).attr('id') === this.id`

Answer (score 0):

In jquery the best way to get to any element is by giving it an ID, and referencing it.

I would structure it the other way around - give the table elements meaningful IDs, and then put the information that I'd like to retrieve in their class attributes.

`<tr id="ms-itmHover..." class="2,2,0">`

And then retrieve it as follows: `$('#ms-itmHover...').attr('class');`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IDs by "mapping" from table row to associated ID thus:

```
var ids = $table.find('tbody > tr').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

You can access individual cells using the `.cells` property of the table row:

```
$table.each('tbody > tr', function() {
    var cell = this.cells[i];   // where 'i' is desired column number
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Go thru all tables, collect all rows and locate their identifiers by your needs:

```js
$('table.ms-viewtable').each(function(){
    $(this).find('tr').each(function(){
        var cells = $(this).children(); //all cells (ths or tds)
        if (this.parentNode.nodeName == 'THEAD') {
            cells.eq(num).html('header row '+this.parentNode.id);
        } else { // in "TBODY"
            cells.eq(num).html('body row '+this.id);
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7RM4/)